# Visual Studio uses XHTML tag closing for HTML5 tags

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, html

Whenever I type out tags that don't require an end tag, Visual Studio adds a forward slash to it, as if they were XHTML.

I think this is unclean and annoying, and I'm hoping anyone can tell me how to fix or work around this issue.

It even happens when I complete `<!DOCTYPE html` with a `>`, and it'll form `<!DOCTYPE html />`.

Comment: This is a huge problem because VS will recognize its fake doctype, <!DOCTYPE html />, as valid HTML5, but no browsers do. I've run into several layout issues because of this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you could do is disable the auto closing tag option in Visual Studio.

Go to Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> HTML >> Formatting

Uncheck the "Auto insert close tag" option.

This will now allow you to type `<br>` (for example) and it won't auto-complete it as `<br />`

Comment: Ahh, wonderful. I have no idea why I didn't try that before. This still allows me to "auto-complete" the closing tags manually, which is great!

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But you still get all those annoying validation warnings that distract from seeing real HTML errors.

Comment: I would recommend [setting the tag-specific option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031694/br-instead-of-br-in-visual-studio?rq=1#answer-13031734) for the tags you want this to happen with (which is pretty much all void elements) rather than the global setting. This way you still get auto-complete on elements that require a closing tag.

Comment: Note that you will probably have to create a new tag under "Client HTML Tags" and will have to restart Visual Studio to see the changes.

Comment: No good for VS 2013, see 321X answer for 2013 onwards. These options have been renamed 'HTML (Web Forms)' so I guess they only work with Web Forms HTML editor? Not going to try it as I don't want nightmares.

Answer (score 19):

For completeness I'm posting this answer. Although we're in 2014 now, with Visual Studio 2013 and HTML5 is getting more and more supported by the major browsers, Visual Studio still behaves the same as ... like always?

The option is just a bit different than in 2010 I assume (based on accepted answer).

[image: Complete element tags in XHTML style with />]

Comment: This option still exists, though it doesn't seem to fix things for me?

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2012, go to *Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting* and click *Tag Specific Options*.

Under *Default Settings -> Client tag does not support contents*, set **Closing tag** to **No closing tag**.

> [image: screenshot of settings interface]