# <br> instead of <br/> in Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, xhtml

I use Visual Studio for teaching HTML. We use HTML 4.01 Transitional. Visual Studio defaults to XHTML 1.0, and I need to solve one problem with a typical difference among these two HTML standards: Whenever we enter `<br>` or `<hr>`, it is automagically changed to `<br />` or `<hr />` respectively. This is great for XHTML, but unwanted when working in HTML 4.01 mode.

So **how to turn off this automagical feature?** We use mainly Visual Studio 2010, and sometimes also 2012 and 2008.

(I know how to easily switch validation to HTMl 4.01 mode, but it still puts slashes to each `<br>`, `<hr>` etc.)

Comment: I didn't know `<br />` wasn't accepted in HTML 4.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko — It is accepted, it just means the same as `<br>&gt;` (although browsers don't support that because they lack proper SGML parsers).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6968052/292060

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting -> Tag Specific Options
```

You may define behavior for each individual tag. Hit <kbd>CTRL + K + D</kbd> to reformat the document and you should see the change.

### Specific Tags

[image]

### Alternative Method (All Tags)

[image]

Comment: Maybe rather default settings instead of tag specific ones? To turn slashes off for all tags without content.

Comment: Yes, the Default Settings folder (above "Client HTML Tags") will work fine too. Updated my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected, something somewhere is still missing or wrong. I selected "no closing tag" as shown in the above picture. But now when I type <br>, it is immediatelly changed to <br></br>.

Comment: Aha, it behaved incorrectly until I restarted Visual Studio. Now it seems to be fine.

Comment: Hmm, never needed a restart to see changes, but glad it works. As note, if you take the time to customize your formatting, make sure to backup your settings file so that you can restore it if needed (or put it on another machine).

Comment: No, I am not going to backup before I do these changes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but even more relevant today.

In Visual Studio 2015, Tools, Options:

[image: Tools | Options in Visual Studio 2015]

Answer (score 0):

```
Tool -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Format -> Tag Specific Options... -> Client HTML Tags -> br
```

Answer (score 0):

For those writing CSHTML and have this problem, I fixed it by modifying settings under...

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Razor (ASP.NET Core) - Advanced
```

- Format On Type = False
- Auto Insert Closing Tag = False

[image]